# What is the pole frequency of a three-phase LC filter?

Tags: ac, filter, passive-networks, three-phase, cutoff-frequency

Suppose I have this configuration:

[image]

Assume L1=L2=L3 and C1=C2=C3. What is the pole frequency of this filter?

Edit: As mcmiln says, this is not identical to the question here:
[Cut Off Frequency in three phase LC filter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/179025/cut-off-frequency-in-three-phase-lc-filter)

I want the closed form (and preferably derrivation) of the filter pole.

Comment: Delta-Y transform and \$\frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{LC}}\$?

Comment: @MattYoung Why the transform in this case? That's one of those details that's tripping me up, and I'm hoping for an idiot check...

Comment: I mean, I think it should be \$\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{2LC}}\$, with no transform necessary. A delta-y transform throws in a factor of 3, and I'm not sure that's needed, but I'm not 100% sure it's not...

Comment: My thought was make the analysis easier. I don't work with 3 phase, and have long since forgotten the rules from my undergrad electric power course.

Comment: Apologies on the flag. This is clearly different in that you are interested in the derivation I believe.

Comment: Is there no load? The load should effect the pole.

Comment: @laptop2d Assume a resistive load. That shouldn't move the pole.

Comment: Going way out on a limb here.  Would superposition apply to this analysis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Ground is defined as the common node of the 3 voltage sources. There's no load attached.

I threw this into a symbolic math solver and get the following relations (a.k.a. sorry, no derivation):

\begin{gather}
V_{R1} = \frac{2 LC \omega^2 - 1}{3 LC \omega^2 - 1} V_1\\
V_{R2} = \frac{V_1 (4 LC \omega^2 - 1) + j \sqrt{3}}{2(3 LC \omega^2 -1)}\\
V_{R3} = \frac{V_1 (4 LC \omega^2 - 1) - j \sqrt{3}}{2 (3 LC \omega^2 - 1)}\\
I_{V1} = \frac{j C V_1 \omega}{3 LC \omega^2 - 1}\\
I_{V2} = \frac{-C \omega (j V_1 - 3 \sqrt{3})}{2( LC \omega^2 - 1)}\\
I_{V3} = \frac{-C \omega(j V_1 + 3 \sqrt{3})}{2(3 LC \omega^2 - 1)}
\end{gather}

I'm relatively certain voltage source currents are assumed to flow into the source to ground.

Note that this assumes 120 degree out of phase sources (\$V_2 = \frac{V_1}{2} - j \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\$, \$V_3 = \frac{V_1}{2} + j \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\$)

I'm unfamiliar with how to compute 3-phase filter frequencies, but hopefully this should be enough that someone else more knowledgeable can use these relations and find a filter frequency.

I do see a common factor of \$3 LC \omega^2 -1\$ in the denominator for all of these equations, so my best guess is there's poles at

\begin{gather}
\omega = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{3LC}}
\end{gather}

I did a quick simulation with LTSpice, and it appears that this analysis does correctly predict the pole for \$V_{R1}\$.

Comment: Having beaten my head on it some more, I think your answer is correct. I'm going to accept your answer, then give an analytical derivation that matches in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pole frequency of any LC circuit is \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$, we can derive the pole frequency by determining what the L and C are as seen by the input and output terminals. Define V1 and V2 as the inputs, and R1 and R2 as the outputs.

Between V1 and V2 are L1 and L2, so our inductance is 2L.

Between R1 and R2 are C1, in parallel with the series combination of C2 and C3. That's C + .5C, or 1.5C.

So LC in this case is 2L * 1.5C, or 3LC. And our pole frequency is \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3LC}}\$.

Another direction we can analyze from is by converting the capacitive load from delta to wye. Define our input to be line-to-neutral, and our output to be cap-to-neutral. Our inductance is now just L. Our capacitance went from C to 3C in the delta-wye conversion. So we still get \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3LC}}\$.